# Babel option clash in scrlttr2 letter

Tags: koma-script, babel, letters, scrlttr2

I want to use babel with the english option in an scrlttr2 letter, in order to change `\today` and descriptions for KOMA variables such as `fromphone` from german to english ('Phone' instead of 'Telefon' etc.). However, I am getting an option clash for babel

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.20 \usepackage
                [utf8]{inputenc}
```

This is the document:

```
\documentclass[
    sender,
    paper=a4,
    version=last,
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV=13,
    BCOR=0mm
    ]{scrlttr2}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Set Font: sans serif Latin Modern
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Set Page layout:
\usepackage{changepage}
\changepage{+3cm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{-5cm}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\LoadLetterOption{thesender}

\begin{document}
% subject, date, place:
\setkomavar{subject}{Application as Test}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{place}{City}

% Set recipient of letter
\begin{letter}{
    Company\\
    Street 233\\
    12345 City
}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}

\selectlanguage{english}
\dots

Yours sincerely,

\vspace{1cm} \includegraphics[width=4cm]{signature}  \\
Name

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and the `thesender.lco` file:

```
\ProvidesFile{thesender.lco}

\KOMAoptions{%
 fromurl=false,
locfield=wide,
fromalign=left,
foldmarks=off,
firsthead=false
}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
  Street 9\\
  14524 City%
}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{test@test.com}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0653/52554325}

\setkomavar{location}{%
  \raggedright{%
  \usekomavar{fromname}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
  }%
}
% ============================

\setkomavar{frombank}{}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
% ====================
```

I don't see that I'm using babel twice with different options or something like that. Apparently though (according to the immediate help), babel has been loaded with the ngerman option. Does anyone see the problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the error message you describe.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. What other information could be useful?

Comment: check in the log-file the path of the thesender.lco, you are probably loading not the one you think you are using.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike that was it! Somehow the 'sender.lco' file was loaded (which is located in the same directory). I don't know why, because I never specify that I want to load this file. Anyways moving the .tex and .lco file in a separate folder solved the problem.